# Are there infinitely many unitary matrices?

Tags: matrices, unitary-matrices

Will there be infinitely many unitary matrices of the form of $U_{n \times n}$ with complex coefficients?

How about unitary matrices of the same form but with only real coefficients?

---

(Not a homework question, just a curious thought).

Comment: There are infinitely many orthonormal basis.

Comment: It is enough to prove for $n=2$. Then you can complete it to a block matrix with $I_{n-2}$ as one block.

Comment: If you try to explain enough conditions instead of "the same form" maybe some not obvious results can be concluded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The unitary matrices with real coefficients are the orthogonal matrices.  That is, $O(n)\subset U (n)$.

In dimension two, there are uncountably many orthogonal matrices,  the rotations:  $\begin{pmatrix}\cos\theta&-\sin\theta\\\sin\theta&\cos\theta\end{pmatrix}$, for $\theta\in [0,2\pi)$, forming $SO(2)\subset O(2)$.

$SO(2)$ is thus isomorphic to the *circle group*, sometimes denoted $U(1)$.

You can use induction to prove it for $n\gt2$, as suggested in the comments by @lhf.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! This is what I wanted!

Answer (score 3):

Any rotation matrix is unitary, and there is an uncountable infinity even of $2 \times 2$ kind.

Comment: (+1) Thank you for the example and explanation.